# Converting unicode object to list after retrieval from database

Tags: python, django, select, unicode

In Django, I'm getting some values from a select field using `request.POST.getlist('tags')`, so when I store this information in MySQL I end up with something like this: `u"['literature']"`. I think this is pretty reasonable and even desirable since I don't want to use another table to store this information. Obviously, the problem comes when I try to retrieve that information because, as expected, I get this:

```
u'['
u'u'
u"'"
u'l'
u'i'
u't'
u'e'
.
.
.
```

(assuming this tag is literature, for example).

How can I transform this unicode object into a Python list?. Is there a better approach?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Create another table.

Databases are designed to be used in a particular way, why try to force them to store information in a way they are not meant to?

There are other solutions to this, but the best answer is use the database as it was intended, it will be easier in the long run.

Comment: As I said, I don't want to use another table because this is a very small amount of data. Another table would mean another JOIN which, I think, is more expensive than the processing of a string in Python.

Comment: a) Is performance really that big an issue? Premature optimisation is a bad thing. b) It's more reliable, and more usable, both python-side and anything else you use to access the dictionary. It's also more flexible for other users of your database (other programs, people, whatever).

Comment: Certainly it's more flexible and maybe that's a good reason I need to think about. As for optimization, I don't think this qualifies as premature optimization because maybe using a table for this won't scale but I have to admit I'm not sure I'm going to receive enough traffic for that to be a problem. Do you know of an estimate (traffic-wise) when performance is an issue for this particular kind of task?.

Comment: @RobertSmith I don't, and the best thing to do here is test it. See the performance, you might actually be surprised. Databases are designed to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Alright, you made me rethink this approach. Now, what's wrong with serializing as other people here are suggesting?.

Comment: @RobertSmith Nothing **wrong** with it exactly, more you won't be using the database as intended. You won't be able to do queries for rows that contain a specific item, You will have to implement something to deserialize everywhere you use it, You are more likely to have problems with column lengths, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Use `json` to convert to JSON before writing, and from JSON after reading. Or use one of the several implementations of `JSONField` in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

does this help?

```
>>> import ast
>>> lst = ast.literal_eval(u"['literature']")
>>> lst
['literature']
>>> isinstance(lst, list)
True
```

but the better approach would be to proper serialize the list before storing as a string. you could use one of the existing pickle implementations, json, or roll your own (since it does not have to be generic, it could be a simple oneliner like `"SENTINAL".join(list)`.... not that I'd recommend the latter, though)

Comment: Well, that certainly helps (+1), but what do you think about the answer given by Lattyware?.

Comment: well, he is certainly right; but IMO, practicality beats purity. It's a tradeoff. in the end, only you can decide.

Comment: @ch3ka While I agree practicality beats purity, I don't see that using your solution is really any easier than adding a table. Definitely not significantly enough to make it a better option.

Comment: @Lattyware I don't think any approach is generally "better". If he does not want to use an extra table, not using an extra table seems "better", if he does not mind, using an extra table is maybe slightly "better", and definitely more "pure".

Comment: @ch3ka You say if he does not want to use an extra table, well, why does he not? If it's arbitrary, then it's pretty irrelevant. I would definitely describe an extra table as better as it allows you to use the database to it's fullest extent.